# send SMS using GPRS in MIDlet

Tags: java, java-me, sms, midlet

i want to send a SMS using GPRS in MIDlet...
anyone can help me??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I assume you have looked at JSR120 but don't want to use it. Are you asking about websites that you can contact over HTTP to tell them to feed a SMS to your mobile network operator?

Answer (score 0):

Sending SMS is a HUGE beast to conquer.  Now I don't know the first thing about j2me, but I do know a bit about SMS since I was at one point working on a similar project (abandoned for the reason below).

The short end of it is that you MUST use a GSM carrier to send SMS if you don't know what carrier to send to.  This is because carriers know how to send the message to the appropriate cell phone.

You could send via email 5554441234@carrierdomain.com but the problem comes with the fact that you have to know which carrier the phone number points to.

Once upon a time you could tell the carrier by the second set of three digits xxxYYYxxxx (the y's), but you can no longer do this because of phone number portability.

In short, check out [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/), but you'll still need to send via GSM (you can get PCI cards that hold SIM cards), or you can pay a [subscription](http://www.bulksms.com/int/?gclid=CPWXvYvVnaACFQk65QodZ270eg).